# Tensor core makeup

Tags: adder

I understand that a normal CPU works through adder circuits in their cores.

Is a gpu core still based on adder circuits with a different instruction set or is it physicaly a different circuit?

Comment: what do you mean when you say `CPU works through adder circuits`?

Comment: C'mon now, if you are asking that you know what an adder circuit is in a cpu. Is a gpu core made up of adder circuits or do they usually have a unique circuit?

Comment: Neither CPUs nor GPUs are based on adder circuits, but both can do addition as well as many other mathematical operations.

Comment: Yes that's true, but if we went through each component of a modern CPU we'd be here all day. Therefore we have to generalize it some. So do GPUs still perform math the same way as most CPUs? Through adders and circuits for the other operations?

Comment: To generalize, they're both composed circuits formed from transistors that do computation. The difference is primarily the organization of those circuits, which is why they're programmed in a somewhat different way and used to do different types of computation.

Comment: Yes we know they have specific tasks. Is it the same circuits though? Is it the same adders and subtractors used in CPUs?

Comment: If you're talking about adders and subtractors, probably they're close enough that you'd consider them the same. Asking opinion questions is frowned on though, so better to be more specific in your question or it might be locked.

Comment: That's not opinion.

Comment: The fact that both GPUs and CPUs have adders, while correct, misses the bigger picture. GPUs have *lots* of them (multipliers too) that run in parallel.

Comment: @JasonMichaels I was asking what  you mean by `works through` ... perhaps something is lost because of translation from your native language ... a CPU uses adders, but I do not know if that is synonymous with `works through adders`

Answer (score 1):

GPUs are arithmetic-optimized arrays of compute cores. They have fairly extensive math-oriented instruction sets that handle a wide palette graphics workloads. They are an evolution of ‘vector processors’ or ‘array processors’, that have grown more complex and CPU-like over time.

Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51344018/why-can-gpu-do-matrix-multiplication-faster-than-cpu

One of the things these feature-rich GPU cores happen to be able to do well, besides their graphics wheelhouse, is much of the inner-loop math needed for neural networks, especially multiply-accumulates (MACs) spanning over large arrays.

So, yes, GPUs become ‘tensor’ (neural network) processors by being programmed to do so. This bit of serendipity is what drove NVidia into the AI space.

Neural network ASICs like Habana, Graphcore, Google TPU, and dozens of other AI chip startups take this a step further. They have architectures that focus on *only* the operations needed for neural processing (including fast MAC), and add some AI-specific functions such as nonlinear thresholding (ReLU) that mimics neural response. This makes them much more efficient and faster than GPU-based solutions. They do sacrifice some flexibility however.

Comment: What circuits do they use though? Lol

Comment: Research ‘GPU architecture’ to get a taste. The main idea is that they are massively parallel single-instruction / multiple data (SIMD) machines that can process data in much bigger chunks than a CPU.

Comment: And yes, GPUs have adders (ALUs) just like a CPU. Lots of them. Multipliers too.

Comment: Thank you. That's what I was asking.